# Finding element's position relative to the document

Tags: javascript, dom

What's the easiest way to determine an elements position relative to the document/body/browser window?

Right now I'm using `.offsetLeft/offsetTop`, but this method only gives you the position relative to the parent element, so you need to determine how many parents to the body element, to know the position relaltive to the body/browser window/document position.

This method is also to cumbersome.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can traverse the `offsetParent` up to the top level of the DOM.

```
function getOffsetLeft( elem )
{
    var offsetLeft = 0;
    do {
      if ( !isNaN( elem.offsetLeft ) )
      {
          offsetLeft += elem.offsetLeft;
      }
    } while( elem = elem.offsetParent );
    return offsetLeft;
}
```

Comment: No it does not, when any parent (especially html element!!!) has margins, paddings or borders.

Comment: regarding the margin stuff... it might help to set the box-sizing to border-box... or something along those lines... nothing that can't be fixed...

Comment: First,you need to decide whether to take account of border and margin according to box-sizing. Second, the collapsed margin should be considered. And last, there will be more complicated situation in the future which would make this answer worse.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? This is outdated and poorly performing. Do yourself a favor and use getBoundingClientRect() as suggested in the other answers.

Comment: it needs to be relative some element. only gets you the global offsetLeft. i see that is the question so I guess correct. I have another case which is relative to any other parent. i guess i can rewrite this. thanks!

Answer (score 221):

You can get *top* and *left* without traversing DOM like this:

```
function getCoords(elem) { // crossbrowser version
    var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

    var body = document.body;
    var docEl = document.documentElement;

    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
    var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docEl.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;

    var clientTop = docEl.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
    var clientLeft = docEl.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

    var top  = box.top +  scrollTop - clientTop;
    var left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft;

    return { top: Math.round(top), left: Math.round(left) };
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account the parents' offsets. It's only relative to the viewport

Comment: @Nickey that's not true—the viewport position, plus the scroll offset checks,  yield the coordinates relative to the whole document.

Comment: Can be buggy on mobile devices http://stackoverflow.com/a/32623832/962634 Need research

Comment: Why you subtract clientTop/clientLeft?

Comment: @Teemoh clientTop / clientLeft corresponds to border values on the `<html>` element.

Comment: Nonsense. Any number of ancestors can be scrolled. There is no way to compute the offset without traversing DOM. There is no SIMPLE way to compute the offset at all. Any solution that can do this RELIABLY is over 1kloc.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski I agree that DOM traversing is needed to handle all cases (e.g. margin:auto on `<html>` element combined with `width: 50vmin` and multiple overflow:auto elements in the current DOM path). However, if you only need to support modern browsers (basically up-to-date Blink, Gecko and Webkit), you need maybe 20 lines of code. You do have to check `.offsetParent` recursively, though.

Answer (score 210):

You can use [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to retrieve element position relative to the viewport.

Then use [`document.documentElement.scrollTop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16618863/368691) to calculate the viewport offset.

The sum of the two will give the element position relative to the document:

```
element.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

Comment: Relative to the viewport is not the same as relative to the document.  If the page is scrolled down a bit then the the top relative to the viewport will be a smaller number than the top relative to the document.

Comment: he starts relative to the viewport and adds scrollY to get it relative to the document.

Comment: `document.documentElement.scrollTop` does not work in Safari, use `window.scrollY` instead

Comment: getBoundingClientRect() calculates the bounding rectangle of the element and all its descendants. If the element has overflow: visible, it can have descendants outside of the element's layout rectangle, descendants BIGGER than itself, descendants arbitrarily displaced with a CSS transform, and a dozen other edge cases.

Comment: awesome man, this helped to get the position relative to document of aggrid row.

Answer (score 15):

I've found the following method to be the most reliable when dealing with edge cases that trip up offsetTop/offsetLeft.

```
function getPosition(element) {
    var clientRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {left: clientRect.left + document.body.scrollLeft,
            top: clientRect.top + document.body.scrollTop};
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[`document-offset`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/document-offset) (*3rd-party script*) is interesting and it seems to leverage approaches from the other answers here.

#### Example:

```
var offset = require('document-offset')
var target = document.getElementById('target')
console.log(offset(target))
// => {top: 69, left: 108}
```

Answer (score 7):

I suggest using

```
element.getBoundingClientRect()
```

as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18673641/1439191)
instead of manual offset calculation through *offsetLeft*, *offsetTop* and *offsetParent*. as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598797/1439191)
Under some circumstances*  the manual traversal produces invalid results. See this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/pC8Kgj

*When element is inside of a scrollable parent with static (=default) positioning.

Comment: You can make the offset calculation work also by incorporating scrollLeft and scrollTop into it.

Comment: But I found `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` don't take into account CSS3 transforms, which `getBoundingClientRect()` does. So that's a case the results may be invalid. If you need it, you can get an element's offset relative to parent (like `offsetLeft`) using `(element.getBoundingClientRect().left - parent.getBoundingClientRect().left)`.

Comment: should def get higher up; these values are far more useful, and all in one call too!

Answer (score 6):

For those that want to get the x and y coordinates of various positions of an element, relative to the document.

```
const getCoords = (element, position) => {
  const { top, left, width, height } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  let point;
  switch (position) {
    case "top left":
      point = {
        x: left + window.pageXOffset,
        y: top + window.pageYOffset
      };
      break;
    case "top center":
      point = {
        x: left + width / 2 + window.pageXOffset,
        y: top + window.pageYOffset
      };
      break;
    case "top right":
      point = {
        x: left + width + window.pageXOffset,
        y: top + window.pageYOffset
      };
      break;
    case "center left":
      point = {
        x: left + window.pageXOffset,
        y: top + height / 2 + window.pageYOffset
      };
      break;
    case "center":
      point = {
        x: left + width / 2 + window.pageXOffset,
        y: top + height / 2 + window.pageYOffset
      };
      break;
    case "center right":
      point = {
        x: left + width + window.pageXOffset,
        y: top + height / 2 + window.pageYOffset
      };
      break;
    case "bottom left":
      point = {
        x: left + window.pageXOffset,
        y: top + height + window.pageYOffset
      };
      break;
    case "bottom center":
      point = {
        x: left + width / 2 + window.pageXOffset,
        y: top + height + window.pageYOffset
      };
      break;
    case "bottom right":
      point = {
        x: left + width + window.pageXOffset,
        y: top + height + window.pageYOffset
      };
      break;
  }
  return point;
};
```

## Usage

- `getCoords(document.querySelector('selector'), 'center')`
- `getCoords(document.querySelector('selector'), 'bottom right')`
- `getCoords(document.querySelector('selector'), 'top center')`

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer, which works in all modern browsers including Safari:

```js
let x = element.getBoundingClientRect().left + window.scrollX
let y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY
```

Comment: From now on I will sort answers by date! Thank you. This works in 2024 chrome.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html Explains the best way to do it, all in all, you are on the right track you have to find the offsets and traverse up the tree of parents.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using jQuery, then you can use `offset()` function. Refer to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) if you want to read up more about this function.