# Display DIV when javascript/jquery condition is met (jsFiddle link included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When the 'rest' time countdown clock reaches 10, I want the "rest" div to
show and display over the "display" div, causing the "display" div to be covered.
When the rest time reaches 5, I want the "rest" div to hide, making the "display" div
reappear.

http://jsfiddle.net/n2learning/9FPG8/2/

Any help would be great,
DK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also solved this problem. The div position must be set absolute, and the position of the 'display' div is also counted using javascript.

Here is [my updated solution](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/9FPG8/14/). I also simplified the code using gaurang's solution:

```js
function countdown(element, minutes, seconds) {
...
        var eld = document.getElementById('display');
        var eldp = getElementPosition(eld);
        if(time == 10){
            el.style.top = eldp.top+'px';
            el.style.left = eldp.left+'px';
            el.style.position = 'absolute';
        } else if (time == 5){
            el.style.display='none';
        }
...
    function getElementPosition(Elem) {
        var offsetLeft = 0, offsetTop = 0;
        do {
            if ( !isNaN( Elem.offsetLeft ) ) {
                offsetLeft += Elem.offsetLeft;
                offsetTop += Elem.offsetTop;
            }
        } while( Elem = Elem.offsetParent );
        return {top: offsetTop, left: offsetLeft };
    }
```

The measuring of element position is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598797/1422309).

Comment: This is great, thanks! getElementPosition() will be very useful considering the div that I need to cover in my production app may not be top:0 and left:0.

Comment: Thanks Derek, I upvoted Encoder's and Gaurang's solutions for their effort too. Some difficult looking tasks can be made also simple. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think solved

http://jsfiddle.net/9FPG8/10/

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle udpated.
http://jsfiddle.net/9FPG8/11/

```
CSS
    #rest.onTop {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
```

JS

```
 if(time == 10){
              document.getElementById("rest").className="onTop";              
        } else if(time == 5){
             document.getElementById("rest").style.display="none";
        } else if(time == 0) {
            el.innerHTML = "Times up!";    
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for submitting this. - DK