# Getting the correct coordinates of a canvas touch event

Tags: html, canvas, position

I am facing problems getting the correct coordinate of touch event. This is my markup

```
<div class="board">
<canvas width="595" height="595" id="bgCanvas"></canvas>
<canvas width="595" height="595" id="liCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.board{
 width:595px;
 height:595px;  
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 left:21px;
 top:230px;
}
.board canvas{
position:absolute;
}
```

and the code, note that I have I already added touch event listener to liCanvas

```
evX= ev.targetTouches[0].pageX- liCanvas.offsetLeft
```

but I'm not getting the right value, I mean I want evX=0 when I touch on the upper left corner of the canvas. Please help me

Comment: what value are you getting?

Comment: i'm getting 11 for evX,116 for evY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

offsetLeft gives the position of element with respect to your board but you want it with respect to body so use the code given below

```
function getOffsetLeft( elem )
{
    var offsetLeft = 0;
    do {
      if ( !isNaN( elem.offsetLeft ) )
      {
          offsetLeft += elem.offsetLeft;
      }
    } while( elem = elem.offsetParent );
    return offsetLeft;
}

evX= ev.targetTouches[0].pageX- getOffsetLeft(liCanvas);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598743/finding-elements-position-relative-to-the-document)

Comment: Thank you very very much Ankit..I was stuck there for the last four days

Comment: @LamiaMehreen if it really helped you then you can accept it by ticking the mark at the left side of answer

Comment: pardon I did tick the arrow but it didnt work properly.. sorry didnt notice

Answer (score 7):

The accepted solution work when arborescence is simple, but for some cases (mine for example) when there can be multiple nested scrolling parents it won't work as intended.

Another solution which work in every cases I have see so far is to use

```
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
evX = ev.targetTouches[0].pageX - rect.left,
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `getBoundingClientRect` and `clientX` and `clientY` (instead of `pageX` and `pageY`) to extract the event coordinates and offset coordinates. Because they are all relative to the viewport, the event coordinates on the canvas can be correctly computed.

For the source code and the demo, please check out [my example](https://leimao.github.io/blog/HTML-Canvas-Touch-Drawing/).