# jQuery SVG animate : scroll and fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to implement a codrops plugin I found and it's working quite well but I have trouble when it comes to improve it.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/12/30/svg-drawing-animation/

My page is divided into three sections, when you click on one of the three sections on the menu, the content fades in.

http://alexandrebeaumont.com/so/layout.png

When you scroll down my animations load perfectly but I would like them to be reloaded each time you click on the menu because now, if I scroll in one section, the animations are launched in everyone of them...

**EDIT** I pasted the whole code since after reading again the script I'm not sure at all what could giver me my solution

```
    (function() {

'use strict';

var docElem = window.document.documentElement;

window.requestAnimFrame = function(){
    return (
        window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
        function(/* function */ callback){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        }
    );
}();

window.cancelAnimFrame = function(){
    return (
        window.cancelAnimationFrame       || 
        window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozCancelAnimationFrame    || 
        window.oCancelAnimationFrame      || 
        window.msCancelAnimationFrame     || 
        function(id){
            window.clearTimeout(id);
        }
    );
}();

function SVGEl( el ) {
    this.el = el;
    this.image = this.el.previousElementSibling;
    this.current_frame = 0;
    this.total_frames = 60;
    this.path = new Array();
    this.length = new Array();
    this.handle = 0;
    this.init();
}

SVGEl.prototype.init = function() {
    var self = this;
    [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'path' ) ).forEach( function( path, i ) {
        self.path[i] = path;
        var l = self.path[i].getTotalLength();
        self.length[i] = l;
        self.path[i].style.strokeDasharray = l + ' ' + l; 
        self.path[i].style.strokeDashoffset = l;
    } );
};

SVGEl.prototype.render = function() {
    if( this.rendered ) return;
    this.rendered = true;
    this.draw();
};

SVGEl.prototype.draw = function() {
    var self = this,
        progress = this.current_frame/this.total_frames;
    if (progress > 1) {
        window.cancelAnimFrame(this.handle);
        this.showImage();
    } else {
        this.current_frame++;
        for(var j=0, len = this.path.length; j<len;j++){
            this.path[j].style.strokeDashoffset = Math.floor(this.length[j] * (1 - progress));
        }
        this.handle = window.requestAnimFrame(function() { self.draw(); });
    }
};

SVGEl.prototype.showImage = function() {
    classie.add( this.image, 'show' );
    classie.add( this.el, 'hide' );
};

function getViewportH() {
    var client = docElem['clientHeight'],
        inner = window['innerHeight'];

    if( client < inner )
        return inner;
    else
        return client;
}

function scrollY() {
    return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/5598797/989439
function getOffset( el ) {
    var offsetTop = 0, offsetLeft = 0;
    do {
        if ( !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
            offsetTop += el.offsetTop;
        }
        if ( !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) ) {
            offsetLeft += el.offsetLeft;
        }
    } while( el = el.offsetParent )

    return {
        top : offsetTop,
        left : offsetLeft
    };
}

function inViewport( el, h ) {
    var elH = el.offsetHeight,
        scrolled = scrollY(),
        viewed = scrolled + getViewportH(),
        elTop = getOffset(el).top,
        elBottom = elTop + elH,
        // if 0, the element is considered in the viewport as soon as it enters.
        // if 1, the element is considered in the viewport only when it's fully inside
        // value in percentage (1 >= h >= 0)
        h = h || 0;

    return (elTop + elH * h) <= viewed && (elBottom) >= scrolled;
}

function init() {
    var svgs = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#main svg' ) ),
        svgArr = new Array(),
        didScroll = false,
        resizeTimeout;

    // the svgs already shown...
    svgs.forEach( function( el, i ) {
        var svg = new SVGEl( el );
        svgArr[i] = svg;
        setTimeout(function( el ) {
            return function() {
                if( inViewport( el.parentNode ) ) {
                    svg.render();
                }
            };
        }( el ), 250 ); 
    } );

    var scrollHandler = function() {
            if( !didScroll ) {
                didScroll = true;
                setTimeout( function() { scrollPage(); }, 60 );
            }
        },
        scrollPage = function() {
            svgs.forEach( function( el, i ) {
                if( inViewport( el.parentNode, 0.5 ) ) {
                    svgArr[i].render();
                }
            });
            didScroll = false;
        },
        resizeHandler = function() {
            function delayed() {
                scrollPage();
                resizeTimeout = null;
            }
            if ( resizeTimeout ) {
                clearTimeout( resizeTimeout );
            }
            resizeTimeout = setTimeout( delayed, 200 );
        };

    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', scrollHandler, false );
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', resizeHandler, false );
}

init();
```

})();

Can't something like this be working ?

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){

    init();

})
```

Comment: Post your code in the question itself, otherwise when the issue is resolved future visitors who come to this question will not be able to see what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit that right away, thanks