# JavaScript getBoundingClientRect() changes while scrolling

Tags: javascript, webapi, getboundingclientrect

I want to have the exact distance between the Y-coordinate of an element an the Y-value=0, which I consider as the top of the document.

```
myElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

But the value of getBoundingClientRect() seems to change while scrolling. How can I get the real distance between myElement and the Y-coordinate=0 (top of document)?

Comment: I would probably close as a dupe of [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element), but why are you using `getBoundingClientRect` and not any of the usual ways to get the offset position relative to the document ?

Comment: @adeneo Which other ways are there?

Comment: See the question above, or look at what jQuery does in `offset`

Comment: for a text node, this is the only solution since `offset()` isn't available.

Answer (score 147):

It is because `getBoundingClientRect()` gets values with respect to the `window`(only the current visible portion of the page), not the `document`(whole page).
Hence, it also takes scrolling into account when calculating its values 
Basically,  `document = window + scroll`

So, to get the distance between myElement and the Y-coordinate=0 (top of document), you would have add the value of vertical-scroll also:

`myElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Your solution is broken for Android Chrome 43, and I think broken if using pinch-zooming on Internet Explorer (my fix was made a long time ago to fix a problem doing it your way).

Answer (score 36):

getBoundingClientRect needs a bit more care to avoid bugs in scrollY/pageYOffset:

```
function absolutePosition(el) {
    var
        found,
        left = 0,
        top = 0,
        width = 0,
        height = 0,
        offsetBase = absolutePosition.offsetBase;
    if (!offsetBase && document.body) {
        offsetBase = absolutePosition.offsetBase = document.createElement('div');
        offsetBase.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;left:0;top:0';
        document.body.appendChild(offsetBase);
    }
    if (el && el.ownerDocument === document && 'getBoundingClientRect' in el && offsetBase) {
        var boundingRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        var baseRect = offsetBase.getBoundingClientRect();
        found = true;
        left = boundingRect.left - baseRect.left;
        top = boundingRect.top - baseRect.top;
        width = boundingRect.right - boundingRect.left;
        height = boundingRect.bottom - boundingRect.top;
    }
    return {
        found: found,
        left: left,
        top: top,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        right: left + width,
        bottom: top + height
    };
}
```

The bugs to avoid are:

- scrolling in Android Chrome since Chrome Mobile 43 has [wrong values](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489206) for scrollY/pageYOffset (especially when the keyboard is showing and you scroll).
- Pinch-zoom in Microsoft IE or Edge causes [wrong values](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/768781/ie10-window-pageyoffset-incorrect-value-when-page-zoomed-breaks-jquery-etc) for scrollY/pageYOffset.
- Some (obsolete) browsers don't have a height/width e.g. IE8

Edit: The above code can be simplified a lot by just using `document.body.getBoundingClientRect()` instead of adding a div - I haven't tried it though so I am leaving my answer as it stands. Also the body needs `margin:0` (reset.css usually does this). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element#11396681) simplifies the code down a lot, while still avoiding the bugs in jQuery.offset()!

Edit 2: [Chrome 61 introduced `window.visualViewport`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/visual-viewport-api) to give correct values for the actual viewport which is probably another way to fix issues; but beware that Android Chrome 66 was still buggy if `Settings -> Accessability -> Force enable zoom` was ticked (bugs with orientation change, focused inputs, absolutely positioned popup wider than viewport).

Comment: Perfect answer. In my case, the document.body.getBoundingClientRect() returned wrong values but this answer worked.

Comment: What is this? `offsetBase = absolutePosition.offsetBase;` absolutePosition is not defined right there...

Comment: @Guntram `absolutePosition` is defined - it is the name of the function (function object) on the first line. This is a 'javascripty' way to store a global variable without adding another global identifier. I admit it shouldn't pass a code review, and the code presumes that the absolutePosition function is defined at the global level. My edit suggests you use document.body as a tidier solution (althought that presumes margin is set to zero on <body>). Also see jQuery $() which is a function that has member properties and member functions.