# How to determine SVG path offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, path

I want to get the vertical offset of a SVG path in pixels. I played with `getBoundClientRect()` and `getBBox()`, but these return too high values. Is there any way to do something like `offset().top` for a normal jQuery element?

Brief example:
https://jsfiddle.net/aq13swsr/2/

I want the amount of pixels between the top black line and the top red line.

Comment: please include a [mcve] so we can see what "too high" means.

Comment: I hope this jsfiddle helps you https://jsfiddle.net/81kom2qa/

Comment: Added an example above.

Comment: Just found out that `getBoundClientRect()` is scroll-dependent which makes it a bit clearer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630035/javascript-getboundingclientrect-changes-while-scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by properly resetting some margins (which are dynamically set using jQuery) before recalculating the next iteration.