# Element.offset / Element.documentOffset resulten in false values

Tags: javascript, html, dart, polymer

Sorry for the indescriptive title, I couldn't come up with anything better.

I've tried getting the position of an Element in the DOM, relative to the document.

I've tried doing it as following:

```
Element element = document.querySelector('.element');
int top = element.documentOffset.y;
int left = element.documentOffset.x;
someAbsoluteFloatingElement.style.top = top.toString() + "px";
someAbsoluteFloatingElement.style.left = left.toString() + "px";
```

'someAbsoluteFloatingElement' is a direct child of the body element. It also has 'position: absolute;' in its CSS properties.

'someAbsoluteFloatingElement' aligns perfectly with the top to 'element', the left value however, is incorrect. I don't know why, I don't know how, I really am lost in this one.

'element' is a child of a custom polymer element. Does this have any influence on the offset of the Element?

Comment: Can you reproduce in https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?

Comment: What is the expected behavior? How should the result be different?

Comment: I've almost reproduced it:  https://dartpad.dartlang.org/7ab3c21dd6debaa98f7d5d003c68e25e The blue box should almost cover the 'T'

Comment: I think it's a bug. I'd try http://stackoverflow.com/a/26230989/217408 instead. Can you please report the bug in the Dart SDK?

Comment: I think I solved it :| . Instead of centering the object with `margin: auto;`, I centered it with `left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0%);`. It seems that the translate() new coordinates are not taken into account.