# set absolute element full width 100% when relative parent has a smaller width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nasty problem with positioning elements:|
So I have a children that need to have full screen width and not the with of relative parent.

```css
body{
  padding: 10px;
}
.container{
  position:relative;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
}
.panel{
  position:relative;
  width:200px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:40px;
}
.panel-body{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-body">
      A Basic Panel
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so the problem is how to bring the `panel-body` in front of all other elements and setting the width 100% but 100% from screen not from parent relative. `The html structure cannot be modified.`

**[fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27228/)**

Comment: `how to bring the panel-body in front of all other elements`, use [css z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). as far as making a child wider than it's parent check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581034/is-there-are-way-to-make-a-child-divs-width-wider-than-the-parent-div-using-css) link.

Comment: You can set `position: fixed` on `.panel-body` instead of `absolute`.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman  That will work until you have to scroll

Comment: Is a wrong HTML, if you set the parents to static positioning it will work with absolute. But if you need relative that parents, the children that needs all the screen should be outside on the html.

Comment: @Kevin Kloet I don't really like that solution and I cannot modify the html structure :|

Comment: i am not sure weather it would work with this html.... not sure.
try some popup instead...

Comment: it might be helpful if you elaborate the situation... :)

Answer (score 2):

This seem to work, I think I fluke it though.

```css
body{
  padding: 10px;
}
.container{
  position:relative;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
}
.panel{
  position:relative;
  width:200px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:40px;
}
.panel-body{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: calc(-50% - 20px - 15px);
  width:100vw;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-body">
      A Basic Panel
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, I forget about `vw`!

Comment: No probs.  The fluke bit was the 20px, I could understand it been 10px, but thinking about it, I assume the body has a default 10px margin, so this might be were the extra 10px has come from..  So  `body-margin + body-padding + container-padding =  10px + 10px + 15px`.  Final = `-50% -35px`

Comment: @Keith the nasty thing is that when you resize the browser the width is buggy :(

Comment: When I run the snippet fullscreen, and resize.  It seems to work.  What browser are you using?..  I've tried it on Chrome / Firefox & Edge.

Comment: Do you mean if you resize smaller than .container class, and you get horizontal scroll bars.. If so a media query will fix that one.

Comment: @Keith check the fiddle to see the differences when you resize the browser (firefox,chrome, same behavior ): https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27235/

Comment: That's just something in fiddle going funky, as you can see using SO snippet works fine, and I've also tested using a HTML server and it works too.

Comment: @Keith actually the snippet has a fixed width and because of that the content runs as in a box, I've added also in my app the vw width and I have the same problem :|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128721/discussion-between-keith-and-burebistaruler).

Comment: I've found the problem, your fiddle has bootstrap loaded..  It has classes for panel, so that will be what's overriding.

Comment: @Keith yes, because of container width, but I use bootstrap on project  :(

Answer (score 2):

If i understand question ...

You will need to define margin left and margin top to negative sum value of all parents offsetLeft and top **or** simple set up position to negative number of offset sum if all parents.

```
function getOffsetLeft( elem )
{
    var offsetLeft = 0;
    do {
      if ( !isNaN( elem.offsetLeft ) )
      {
          offsetLeft += elem.offsetLeft;
      }
    } while( elem = elem.offsetParent );
    return offsetLeft;
}
```

I found some answer for you :

[finding element's position relative to the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598743/finding-elements-position-relative-to-the-document)

Now you know your position and it is very easy to set up new position for element position type absolute .

You wanna some kind of fullscreen . Set x position to  -(sumOfOffsetLeft)
also for y .

For width 100% no need for calculation just use window.innerWidth maybe 
window.innerWidth/100*95 ( 95% of screen ) .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what do you want to do but if you have an element in a smaller relative parent , you can use `position:fixed` for the child, then set bigger width for it; because An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport.
it's good if you want to have a full width and full height child inside a position:relative parent.good luck !