# Retrieve screen coordinates of TextInput from onFocus event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I need to retrieve the position on the screen of a TextInput from the onFocus event. I haven't found documentation about this, my problem is that I cannot find out the element from the event triggered on focus.
Here the code:

```
_handleOnFocus(event) {        
console(event.nativeEvent.target.layout.y); // where is the y coordinate?
}
```

The callback is inserted here:

```
<TextInput onFocus={              
onFocus={event => {this._handleOnFocus(event);}}} ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by `event.target.offsetTop` but consider that it will return offset from closest not static parent. If you need absolute offset, please refer to this question: [Finding element's position relative to the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598743/finding-elements-position-relative-to-the-document)