# React How to Dynamically set offsetTop with height to a div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, offset

I am working on a dashboard part of a site and i am very new to reactjs.
I am trying fit everything on a screen so that the user does not have to scroll expect for the table, i hope the code below defines the situation better.

Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.tableHeightOffset();
}

tableHeightOffset() {
    var getOffset = this.containerLine.offsetTop;
    this.setState({ getOffset });
}

render() {

    var findTableHeight = this.state.getOffset;
    const tableHeight = {
      height: 'calc(100vh - ' + findTableHeight + 'px' + ')'
    }

    return (
        <div className="table-responsive" style={tableHeight} ref={el => this.containerLine = el}>
    )
}
```

How do i get the offset to change when the browser resize or there is a update on the site ?

Also I get the value on findTableHeight but it is not getting the offset from to the top of the window. I was suppose to get 161px of offsetTop but i am only getting 46px.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a resize listener to the window, in order to calculate the new hight. This could be done in componentDidMount():

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.tableHeightOffset);
}
```

Don't forget to remove it before unmounting the component:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.tableHeightOffset);
}
```

Also offsetTop returns the offset from the parent. In order to find the offset relative to the document, check this article: [Finding element's position relative to the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598743/finding-elements-position-relative-to-the-document)

Comment: I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of undefined" when resizing the screen. I am not sure what's the reason behind this.

Comment: Try defining the ref in the constructor:
constructor() {
    super();
    this.containerLiner = React.createRef();
}
And after:
        <div className="table-responsive" style={tableHeight} ref={ this.containerLine }/>

Answer (score 0):

Here you have api to listen for window size change https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event use it to dynamically change your offset.